# Capturing the value of dynamically created TextBox and DropDownList in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I am stuck in an issue, tried googling but could not find any solution.

I have created controls dynamically in `Page_Load` and I have a static button.

When the button is clicked, I need to capture user entry in those controls.

Now when I am trying to access the control using its unique id, error is being returned as the control is not available at runtime. :(

For loop - starts

```
    if (dr["Type"].ToString().Trim() == "DropDown")
    {
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.Id = "ddl" + Convert.ToString(Counter);
        ddl.DataTextField = "Text";
        ddl.DataValueField = "Value";
        ddl.DataSource = ds1;
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.EnableViewState = true;
        cell.Controls.Add(ddl);
    }
    else if (dr["QuestionType"].ToString().Trim() == "TextBox")
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "txt" + Convert.ToString(Counter);
        txt.EnableViewState = true;
        cell.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
    table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Even if i do a `FindControl` in `Btn_click` function, it says that the panel has 0 controls.

```
var textbox = (TextBox)pnlMidTermFeedback.FindControl("txt5");
```

textbox is always NULL, although I have a control `txt5`. I can see it when I do a <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Please help.

Comment: I resolved it by adding the control details to the Viewstate implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically created controls must be recreated on every postback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Set values and properties of controls specified in markup
        ...
    }

    // Create new controls and add them to the panel
    ...
}
```

They will then be available in the button event handler, and contain the data entered by the user.